# CodeIgniter: I can't remove the item from the cart

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to remove the item from the cart by issuing a command in the controller. Here's my code:

```
function remove($rowid) {   
    $data = array(
        'rowid'   => $rowid,
        'qty'     => 0
    );

    $this->cart->update($data);

    redirect('bookings');
}
```

Now, when I click the link to remove the item it return an error "404 page not found". This is the example URL:

http://example.com/reservation/bookings/remove/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c

The "remove()" function is located in the same file as my "add()" which work without problem.

Here's the code of my "add()" function:

```
public function add()
{
    $this->load->model('Bookings_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('cart');

    $bookings = $this->Bookings_model->get($this->input->post('id'));

    $data['type'] = $this->input->post('type');
    $data['checkin'] = $this->input->post('checkin');
    $data['checkout'] = $this->input->post('checkout');
    $data['nights'] = (strtotime($data['checkout']) - strtotime($data['checkin'])) / (60 * 60 * 24);

    $insert = array(
        'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
        'name' => $bookings->room_type,
        'checkin' => $data['checkin'],
        'checkout' => $data['checkout'],
        'nights' => $data['nights'],
        'price' => $bookings->default_price,
        'qty' => 1,
        'amount' => $bookings->default_price
    );

    $this->cart->insert($insert);

    redirect('bookings');
}
```

I tried everything but it's two days now and I can't still find the solution.

Comment: How's the url to add a product to the cart?

Comment: maybe it should be `'id'   => $rowid,`

Comment: @MihaiIorga that wouldn't result in a 404.

Comment: have you loaded model in `__construct()` ? I can see model loading functions in `add()` but not in `remove()`. Is it bcoz of that?

Comment: the problem is with my routes config: I put `$route['bookings/remove'] = 'bookings/remove';` but i didn't work. it should be `$route['bookings/remove/(:any)'] = 'bookings/remove/$1';'

Comment: @BhuvanRikka yes i need to add also `$this->load->library('cart');` and `$this->load->helper('url');` in remove function. do u recommend putting it under __construct?

Answer (score 2):

use this function to remove item from cart session:

```
function remove($rowid){
    $this->load->library('cart');
    $data = array();
   foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items){
       if($items['rowid'] != $rowid){
           $data[] = array('id' => $items['rowid'],
                           'qty' => $items['qty'],
                           'price' => $items['price'],
                           'name' => $items['name']);
       }
   }

   $this->cart->destroy();
   $this->cart->insert($data);
   redirect('bookings');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use:

```
  public function delete_item($id)
    {            
        $this->db->where('itemid', $id);
        $res = $this->db->delete('mycart');
        return $res; 
    }
```

and in your controller:

```
   function remove()
   {
         $result = $this->model_name->delete_item($id);
         if($result)
                    redirect('view or controller');
```

We cont redirect from model directly.may it wrks sometime but most case it fails...
I Hope It Useful....

```
   }
```